# Spiral equation

Tags: geometry

Considering concentric arcs, of equal developed length, whose start point is aligned:

[image]
[image]

I am looking for the **equation** of the spiral passing through the end points.

Some help to solve this problem will be welcome!

---

Edit: The result

[image]

Comment: How is the yellow curve related to gray arcs on pictures? It doesn't seem to pass through endpoints of those arcs...

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the equation yet. The yellow spiral is a spiral of equation `Xt = -5*t*cos(t)` and `Yt = -5*t*sin(t)`. I put this screenshot to show the equation format I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In polar coordinates, every arc starts at $\theta=0$ and ends at $\theta=L/r$, where $L$ is the length of each arc and $r$ is the radius for respective arc. So this is the equation:
$$\theta=L/r.$$
In Cartesian coordinates:
$$(x,y) = \left(r\cdot\cos\frac Lr,\, r\cdot\sin\frac Lr\right)$$
for $0 < r < \infty.$

The spiral is called **hyperbolic spiral**, or a **reciproke spiral** – see my post [Does the spiral `Theta = L/R` have a name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3766344/does-the-spiral-theta-l-r-have-a-name) and the [answer to it](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3766361/152299).

Comment: For those reading the answer, I would just like to add that the x-axis is vertical up, and y is pointing to the right.

Comment: Thank you very mutch, I solved it with `t1=Rmin=0.01`, `t2=Rmax=0.05`, `xt=1000*t*sin(0.001*length/t)`, `yt=1000*t*cos(0.001*length/t)`