# Does the spiral Theta = L/R have a name?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

**Note:** I intentionally left the equation in the title in plain text instead of MathJax, so it is searchable.

Here is a spiral's equation in polar coordinates:
$$\theta=L/r,$$
and in Cartesian coordinates:
$$(x,y) = \left(r\cdot\cos\frac Lr,\, r\cdot\sin\frac Lr\right)$$
for $0 < r < \infty$ and some positive constant $L$.

It appeared here, at Math SE, as an answer to the [Spiral equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765595/spiral-equation) question.

Does this curve have a name?

Comment: It is called an hyperbolic spiral. https://www.google.com/search?q=hyperbolic+spiral&sxsrf=ALeKk00i2NlA9X96PVCVcSsfIcwoZ9hOzg:1595490525924&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin1aiw8eLqAhUOC-wKHZomALcQ_AUoAXoECBIQAw&biw=1920&bih=969

Comment: @YvesDaoust Quick and precise. Thank you. :) I'd like you like to post it as an answer, so I can put a green tick on it.

Comment: @CiaPan You can also answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @PaulFrost Sure I can But I like to give a green tick to someone. Or is this question too simple for anybody to care...? :)

Comment: ...and ticked. :)

Comment: More generaly it is member of the family of so-called "archimedean spirals" (http://xahlee.info/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/ArchimedeanSpiral_dir/archimedeanSpiral.html).

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, I am not after ticks and Henry did the job.

Comment: @CiaPan Sometimes people do not have the time to give an official answer and simply write a short comment which nevertheless answers the question. And frequently that is all what is happening - the question is de facto answered, but it is not  visible at first glance and the question remains forever in the "unanswered queue". Therefore I recommend to wait some time for an official answer. If you get one (as in  the present case), it is okay. Otherwise answer your own question.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you. I often comment, sometimes answer, almost never ask at StackExchange, so I have no big practice in answering _my own questions_ – although there was one exception :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @YvesDaoust said in a comment it is called a *[hyperbolic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_spiral)*, or a *reciproke spiral* as the circle inversion of an Archimedean spiral

Wikipedia has a couple of images, depending on whether you look at one or two arms of the hyperbola underlying $r=\frac a \varphi$

[image]

[image]

Comment: May I ask you which (excellent !) drawing software you use ?

Comment: @JeanMarie As Henry points out int he second paragraph, those are images from Wikipedia. More precisely, from Wikimedia Commons repository, [Link1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hyperbol-spiral-1.svg), [Link2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hyperbol-spiral-2.svg). You'd have to ask their author, a Wikipedian Ag2gaeh about a software. They seem to work mainly in German Wikipedia, here is a link to [the user's talk page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer_Diskussion:Ag2gaeh) at German, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Ag2gaeh) at English Wikipedia..

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks. I should have read more properly what Henry said.